# Authorize Blazor Server App/Pages Based on User Name

Tags: c#, authentication, server, authorization, blazor

I can't seem to find an exact solution to this issue.  I am using windows authentication on my blazor server app and that works fine.  But after someone logs in and is authenticated I want to be able to revoke their authorization if they are not in a list of user names that I indicated.  So in essence I want to authorize by username and not roles.